# React drag and drop with clones

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I've created a repository of SVGs in a react app from which you can pull an SVG on to a "canvas". But, I need there to be 'infinite' copies  of the SVG, so that when you drag one out, there is another copy of it which can be used as well ad infinitum. Any ideas on how to do this?

I've looked at various drag and drop packages (react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd), but none seem to have similar functionality. My only idea is to clone the image onClick; but that seems a little hacky.

Answer (score 7):

Actually you can do that with react-beautiful-dnd. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/40p81qy7v0) is example of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone finding for cloned example :
[Click here for working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-copy-and-drag-forked-bz1bq4?file=/index.js:6677-6702)

Just a gist : You need to make a clone styled component and your snapshot.isDragging will check the current status of the div you are dragging.
Also note if you are dragging a div then your actual list of component should be outside this snapshot function.